# Pyserial read_all() error on macOS 11.6.1 m1 silicon

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

## System information

`OS`: Big Sur 11.6.1 
`silicon`: m1 
`pipenv version`: version 2021.11.23 
`python version`: 3.10 
`pyserial version`: 3.4

## Expected behavior

The following code block is a representation of how the error can be reproduced

```
import serial

port_in_use = serial.Serial('port_name', 921600)
bytes = port_in_use.read_all()
```

## Observed behavior

Pyserial always throws an exception for the use of `read_all()`, due to a call to `in_waiting()`, which I attempted replacing with `inWaiting()`, but to no avail.

### Error message

```
    @property
    def in_waiting(self):
        """Return the number of bytes currently in the input buffer."""
        #~ s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, termios.FIONREAD, TIOCM_zero_str)
>       s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
E       AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'fd'
```

## Question

Is this a known issue, or has anyone found a solution to this problem? If so please share insight, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On M1 I can run your code flawlessly. I gave directly the port name to the serial object as the following:

```py
port_in_use = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-2101837375321')
```

As you can see above, my port name is **"/dev/tty.usbserial-2101837375321"**. You can also find your own serial port name (look for something like "/dev/tty.usbserial" and use the bigger numbered one) from the output of terminal command (after plugged in your cable):

```bash
ls /dev/tty*
```

Should give output like:

```bash
...

/dev/tty                            /dev/ttysa
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/ttysb
/dev/tty.LenovoLivePods-SPP         /dev/ttysc
/dev/tty.debug-console              /dev/ttysd
/dev/tty.usbserial-2101837375320    /dev/ttyse
/dev/tty.usbserial-2101837375321    /dev/ttysf
/dev/tty.wlan-debug                 /dev/ttyt0
/dev/ttyp0

...
```

If all of not helps, already installed serial python libraries may be mixed, so try to uninstall all serial libraries and install just pyserial library again, as followings:

```bash
pip3 uninstall serial
pip3 uninstall pyserial
```

```bash
pip3 install pyserial
```